# Repeater or similar for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I just started playing with Windows Phone 7 today, and with no background in Silverlight I have some questions I need sorted.

On the app I'm working on, I get a json set returned from a web service. I create my array with the objects which contain a title, a description, an image, a link etc etc. Now, for presenting this I need to accomplish two tasks:
1. I need to allow the page to scroll (preferrable only the data part and not the header)
2. I need to present this data in a good looking manner, and was thinking something like a repeater.

Anyone got any good starting tips for a n00b? :p

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You'll be wanting to use the [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) control - this has the repeater functionality you're looking for. Here's a [good tutorial](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/) explaining how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Gergely is right, the Listbox is the general right choice. However, you should know that the listbox has some performance issues as for now which make scrolling a bit painfull on the actual device. If you have a few records, with different dimensions, you should consider a stackpanel in the itemspaneltemplate.

Example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oren/archive/2010/11/08/wp7-silverlight-perf-demo-1-virtualizingstackpanel-vs-stackpanel-as-a-listbox-itemspanel.aspx